# Merging together identical values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static String[][][] cleanUp(String[][][] array) {
    for (int f = 0; f < array.length; f++) {
        for (int g = 0; g < array[f].length; g++) {
            int position = 0;
            //boolean flag = false;
            int count = 0;
            for (int h = 0; h < array[f][g].length; h++) {
                if (array[f][g][h].equals(array[f][g][h+1])) count++;
                else {
                    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array[f][g]));
                    for (int i = count - 1; i > position; i--) {
                        temp.remove(i);
                        position = i-1 ;
                    }
                    temp.set(position, array[f][g][h] + " (" + count + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Essentially, what I want to do is take a 3D array of strings and have each 1D array in it display quantity for repeated values. For instance, if I had an array of Strings like this:

```
[go, go, go, go, go, go]
[go, stop, stop, stop]
```

it would become:

```
[go (5)]
[go (1), stop (3)]
```

How could I do this, and what is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can start by properly comparing Strings (use equals, not ==)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the 2 outer dimensions of the array are irrelevant to the deduplication. If this is the case, it might be easier to think about how to do this for `String[]`, and then just wrap calls to that method in two for loops to iterate the outer dimensions.

Comment: @Eran Whoops. I fixed that, but it still doesn't work. I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` either way.

Comment: I fail to understand why you need a 3D array! Can you please explain?

Comment: I don't. It's there because I'm using a 3D array in a different part of my code and it was simper to keep it as such. Pham Trung's solution below works ideally for a 1D array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your last inner loop:

```
        int count = 0;
        for (int h = 0; h < array[f][g].length; h++) {
            if (array[f][g][h].equals(array[f][g][h+1])) count++;
            //You dont check for out of bound here, so `h + 1` will cause out of bound error
            else {
                ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array[f][g]));
                for (int i = count - 1; i > position; i--) {
                    temp.remove(i);
                    position = i-1 ;
                }
                temp.set(position, array[f][g][h] + " (" + count + ")");
            }
            //Count is not reset after this, so this will be wrong!
        }
```

How I would do it:

```
        ArrayList<String> tmp  = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int h = 0; h < array[f][g].length; h++) {
            int count = 1;
            while(h + count < array[f][g].length && array[f][g][h].equals(array[f][g][h+count])) 
               count++;
            tmp.add(array[f][g][h] + "(" + count + ")");
            h += count - 1;//Update h to skip identical element
        }
```

ArrayList `tmp` will hold the result for `array[f][g]`, and you should notice how I update `h` accordingly to skip all identical element.

Update: testing [result](http://ideone.com/78VQ8u)

Comment: @CalvinKinzie sorry, I cannot view the link (this is my network problem), however, I have tested my code, result is [here](http://ideone.com/78VQ8u). So I think it is straight forward to use it for three or more dimensional array, you don't need to use `position` anymore :)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I also realised my mistake was that I never put a `array[f][g] = tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]);` after the closing bracket in your code (I would suggest adding that). It's all good now.